# Read multi object json gz file from S3 in python

Tags: python, json, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, gzip

I have some files in a S3 bucket and I'm trying to read them in the fastest possible way. The file's format is gzip and inside it, there is a single multi object json file like this:

```
{"id":"test1", "created":"2020-01-01", "lastUpdated":"2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"}
{"id":"test2", "created":"2020-01-01", "lastUpdated":"2020-01-01T00:00:00.000Z"}
```

What I want to do is load the json file and read every single object and process it. After some research this is the only code that it worked for me

```
import json
import gzip
import boto3
from io import BytesIO

s3 = boto3.resource('s3')
bucket = s3.Bucket("my-bucket")

for obj in bucket.objects.filter(Prefix='my-prefix').all():
    buffer = BytesIO(obj.get()['Body'].read())
    gzipfile = gzip.GzipFile(fileobj=buffer)
    for line in gzipfile:
        json_object = json.loads(line)
        # some stuff with the json_object
```

Anyone knows a better way to read the json object?

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some researches, I found the library [smart-open](https://pypi.org/project/smart-open/) very useful and simply to use.

```
from smart_open import open
import json

s3_client = s3_session.client("s3")
source_uri = 's3://my-bucket/my-path'
for json_line in open(source_uri, transport_params={"client": s3_client}):
    my_json = json.loads(json_line)
```

It uses a stream so you don't need to keep in memory the entire file when you read it. Furthermore, it handles different extensions so I don't need to care about the gz decompression.

Comment: And if your ultimate goal is to create a pandas dataframe, just add one more line:
my_df = pd.DataFrame(my_json)

Answer (score 0):

After you have the buffer, try the following

```
decompressed = gzip.decompress(buffer)
json_lines = json.loads(decompressed)
for json_obj in json_lines:
    # Do stuff
```

Comment: I try your solution but it returned with "TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not '_io.BytesIO'". So I tried to remove the BytesIO, but I still receive an error "json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Extra data: line 2 column 1 (char 76100)", due to the fact that the file contains multi json object I suppose

Comment: Actually, I reviewed you're question one more time and realized I was falsely assuming the zipped file is a json file. However, it is not, it is simply a file containing multiple json objects. Either use your existing working code (you have to json.loads each object/line separately), OR modify the files to be valid json e.g. [{...},{...},{...}] instead of {...} {...} {...} and then you will be able to load all at once.

Comment: Then the way you have described above is the fastest as although each line is valid json, the lines together without a containing array are not valid json and thus cannot be loaded all together using a utility for json objects so loading individually will have to do.